# Separating a code chunk into the main parts and the expected return parts

Tags: ruby, regex, string

What is the best way to separate a code chunk (string) into its "main parts" and its "expected return parts"? Here are my definitions:

- An *expected return part* is a line that matches `/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*=>/` followed by zero or more consecutive lines that do not match `/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*=>/` but match `/[ \t]*#(?!\{)/`.
- A *main part* is any consecutive lines that is not an expected return part.

Main parts and expected return parts may appear multiple times in a code chunk.

Given a string of code chunk, I want to get an array of arrays, each of which includes a flag of whether it is an expected return part, and the string. What is the best way to do this? For example, given a string `code` whose content is:

```
def foo bar
  "hello" if bar
end
#=> foo(true) == "hello"
#=> foo(false) == nil
a = (0..3).to_a
#=> a == [
#          0,
#          1,
#          2,
#          3
#   ]
```

I would like a return that would be equivalent to this:

```
[[false, <<CHUNK1], [true <<CHUNK2], [true, <<CHUNK3], [false, <<CHUNK4], [true, <<CHUNK5]]
def foo bar
  "hello" if bar
end
CHUNK1
#=> foo(true) == "hello"
CHUNK2
#=> foo(false) == nil
CHUNK3
a = (0..3).to_a
CHUNK4
#=> a == [
#          0,
#          1,
#          2,
#          3
#   ]
CHUNK5
```

Comment: I asked a question related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should match all expected returns:

```
^([ \t]*#[ \t]*=>.+(?:\n[ \t]*#(?![ \t]*=>).+)*)
```

Extract and then replace all expected returns from your string with a separator. Then split your string by the separator and you will have all main parts.

Test it here: http://rubular.com/r/ZYjqPQND28

There is a slight problem with your definition pertaining to the regex `/[ \t]*#(?!>\{)/`, by which I am assuming you meant `/[ \t]*#(?!=>)/`, because otherwise

```
#=> foo(true) == "hello"
#=> foo(false) == nil
```

would count as one chunk

Another approach would be to use this [regex](http://rubular.com/r/SJx55bZL66) (completely unoptimised):

```
^([ \t]*#[ \t]*=>.+(?:\n[ \t]*#(?![ \t]*=>).+)*|(?:[ \t]*(?!#[ \t]*=>).+\n)*)
```

to simply split it into chunks correctly, then do a relatively simple regex test on each chunk to see if it is an expected return or main part.

Comment: Your regex does not work correctly if I change `#=>` to `# =>` in the fifth line. Maybe that specification I am asking for is debatable.

Comment: @sawa Correct, I just modified the regex after rereading your question. It now matches `# =>`

Comment: Thanks, your regex works now, I think. Regarding matching `/[ \t]*#(?!>\{)/`, as I stated in the question, that is a necessary condition; there is another condition to not match the other regex. Your regex seems to correctly inforporate them into one.

Comment: And, splitting needs some consideration because the expected returns may appear consecutively.

Comment: @sawa let me know what you find out, I will modify the regex appropriately. Also, have a look at the other approach I suggested.

Comment: @sawa You can still split, just discard the empties.