# The `#=>` convention for expected returns

Tags: ruby, coding-style, convention

It is a Ruby convention to use `#=>` for describing expected returns. I realized that I use `# =>` (with some space or tabs) myself. This is just a convention, and there is no formal specification, so I would like to ask what the convention is among Ruby programmers. Is

1. `#=>` the only correct way or is preferred,
2. `# =>` is preferred, or
3. Either is almost equally used?

And, would there be any reasons to exclude or prefer one form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a convention. At least, I haven't read anywhere about it. I use it myself only because my editor (TextMate) helpfully expands these markers when evaluating code. For example, if I type this line:

```
2 + 3 #
```

And then press TAB, it will insert `=>` after the hash character. The line becomes this:

```
2 + 3 # =>
```

Then if I press a shortcut, it will run the code and insert/update value of corresponding lines after the `# =>` markers.

```
2 + 3 # => 5
```

Also, I personally think that `# =>` looks much more readable than `#=>`.

Comment: Nice to know that information. I use emacs, and I didn't know that TextMate was that sophisticated.

Comment: @sawa: it's great for quickly whipping up answers for stackoverflow :)

Comment: @sawa: You can get similar behavior for Emacs with [rcodetools.el](http://emacsblog.org/2007/07/21/package-faves-rcodetools/) too.

Comment: @jmdeldin That is also great. I didn't know that.